# Quantum integrable models with no classical integrable counterpart

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, integrable-systems

I am looking for examples for quantum integrable systems that have no classical integrable limit.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum integrable models are usually defined via the inverse scattering approach, i.e., by stating an S-matrix that fulfills a number of properties and fixing the particle spectrum. For this reason, it is possible to find a quantum model that is not the quantization of a classical one.

An example for a model without classical counterpart is the **scaling $Z(N)$ Ising model**.
In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510062) paper, the authors state that
"[...] we do not quantize a classical field theory. In fact the quantum field theory considered in this paper is not related (at least to our knowledge) to any classical Lagrangian or field equations of massive particles."

However, that does not mean that a classical counterpart is non-existent, only that it has not been found.

Is that what you meant for or did you ask for theories **with** classical limit, but one that is not integrable?

If I made any mistake, corrections are always welcome!