# Correspondence between quantum and classical integrability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-systems, integrable-systems

I'm looking for connections between quantum and classical integrability. I know quantum integrability is not well-defined, but let us just take one of the popular definitions by promoting the Poisson brackets in the definition of classical integrability to commutators.

Let us focus on the case of $N$ particles with **well-defined classical analog** (i.e., exclude quantum systems with finite dimension, which does not have a well-defined classical limit). Then here are our classical and quantum definitions of integrability, respectively.

**Classical integrability**
$$\{H,I_n\}=0$$
$$\{I_n,I_m\}=0.$$

**Quantum integrability**
$$[H,I_n]=0$$ and
$$[I_n,I_m]=0.$$

My questions are: With above definitions and focusing on $N$-particle with well-defined classical analog

- (i) Does classical integrability imply quantum integrability defined above?
  i.e., if one promotes the Poisson brackets among the integrals of motions into commutators, will they still commute?
- (ii) Does the quantum integrability defined above imply classical integrability? Say, one demotes the commutators among the integrals of motion for your quantum mechanical model into Poisson brackets, will they vanish?

I think both (i) and (ii) may be right as long as we focus on say $N$-particle system with well-defined classical limit. Good examples are the Calogero model and Toda lattice. Both of them are classically and quantum mechanically integrable.  I don't know if there is any counter-example against these two claims. Or someone has found some rigorous proof that (i) and (ii) are true for $N$-particle system with well-defined classical limit

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/491531/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32967/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks! This question is related to, but different from the questions in these links.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of "natural" superintegrable systems failing to translate across the quantization map and certainly not the classical limit. (Actually, these are all described by [classical & quantum Nambu brackets](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.68.085001) which demolishes bogus "proofs"  that NBs could not be quantized. This is why I barely listen to proofs for the non-existence of fish as I'm fishing.)

It is extremely hard to not get confused about quantization to commutators, unless one uses their isomorphs in phase space, namely [Moyal Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_bracket), whose classical limit is PBs, if a classical limit is defined. So, then, the answer to your (ii) is "yes, of course". QM includes CM.

The pioneer fleshing out the systematics of (i), extension/correction of PBs to MBs by suitable ℏ corrections, for integrable systems, is [Hietarinta, J Math Phys 25 1833 (1984)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.526373), and subsequent citers. The key-point is that quantization allows for an infinity of options, and the ones sought and chosen are the ones preserving the symmetry/integrability structure of the classical theory.

Well-meaning finite-dimensional systems do follow suit, as a rule, and I have never seen plausible simple counterexamples in ordinary QM. For strings and recondite QFTs, you may always effectively conceal  ambiguities in their definitions; you appreciate the requirement of good faith here.

Comment: There is also the very nice “ KUŚ, M., 2002. Integrability and non-integrability in quantum mechanics. Journal of Modern Optics, 49(12), pp.1979-1985.”  Unexpected venue for this work but still very nice.

Comment: ... but I got this [2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3819).

Comment: [Weigert 1992](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-2789(92)90053-P) is also making faces... but nothing compelling.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks. I at last got the Kus paper. He appears stunned by Hietarinta's implicit utilization of the Groenewold-VanHove theorem. But that's is precisely the beauty of Hietarinta's spirit. One uses integrability as  guidance for the quantization ordering choice, as we did in [Curtright & Zachos (2002) New J. Phys. **4** 83](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205063).

Comment: more homework from the master...  Thanks!